# How to calculate real path of file in java using relative path?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have created dynamic web project. In that I have written one Java class which opens a properties file and returns the value for a key passed to the function.

But to open the properties file I have to write a whole path like `c:/Apache/webapps/webcontent/resources/system.properties`. But I want to calculate the real path of this file using a relative path.

How to calculate the real path? This is not a servlet, it's a complete Java file having only one class and its methods. How do I calculate the real path of a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load a `File` with a relative path, calling `File.getCanonicalPath()` or `File.getAbsolutePath()` will give you the absolute path.

When using an app server, your working directory will be where your app server was started from, so to get the absolute path to a `File` using a relative path, you would need to do:

```
String relativePath = '/mypath/myfile.txt';
String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativePath);
File file = new File(absolutePath);
```

Comment: If you can load the file using the relative path, you can get the absolute path by calling the above methods on the resulting File object.

Comment: :Having another problem.When I run this as java application it take correct path but when I run this on server it returns wrong path.I am calling this from startup servlet.It changes working directory when I call from servlet.Where eclipse .exe file is present it takes this as the working directory.Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your working directory will be where your app server was started from. If you need to get this location and then a file path relative to it, use `String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativePath);` You can then use `absolutePath` to load your `File`.